# Can I use the TX pin as a normal GPIO output alongside serial communications on the UART?

Tags: gpio, serial, uart, wiring

I'm using the raspberry pi's UART to interface with a third-party radio.  At startup, the radio reads its RX pin (the pi's TX pin) to determine which baud rate should be used.  I'm using Gordon's wiringPi library.  If I configure the TX pin as an output to do the startup signaling, the UART won't work for serial communications after the radio has booted up.  In my testing, the UART seems to remain broken until the pi is restarted.

Is it possible to use the TX pin as both an output and then later as part of the UART?  What am I breaking by setting it to an output before using it for serial communications?